# Cjs-Message: JS LOG: Network Manager is not running, hiding

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, login, networkmanager

> Config: Linux Mint 17.2 (based on: Ubuntu, Debian). Note: same problem on Ubuntu 14

I removed `network-manager` (*via* `apt-get ... remove`).

I rebooted.

Now I cannot login anymore, each time I enter password, the screen turns black 2 seconds, then redisplay login prompt popup.

I can only get access to `tty` <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>
where I can login.

The file `.xsession-erros` ends with :

> **Cjs-Message: JS LOG: Network Manager is not running, hiding...**

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I don't think removing only `network-manager` cause this problem. (may some other packages have removed) or Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/223501)

Comment: I wonder if my system is still expecting network-manager at launch... By the past I felt NM was launched after end of boot... strange.

Comment: @Pandya thank you, but it is a NM issue. Look at my Edit.

Comment: What about installing `network-manager` from tty?

Comment: impossible, *Network is unreachable*

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23826550#23826550